# How to check if a variable has already been declared or not? (IsolatedStorage)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, settings, isolatedstorage

I'm writing an application in C# for Windows Phone 7.
In this application I have some Settings (language and audio).
On the first boot, the application lets you choose, in MainPage.xaml (Start Page) the language and saves the value in the IsolatedStorage.
On the next boots, the application runs automatically on the start menu with the language chosen by the user. The problem is that I can't check the value in the IsolatedStorage, because it's declared when you choose the language on the MainPage.xaml

That's what I did:

In App.xaml I use:

```
RootFrame.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(MainPage.RootFrame_Navigating);
```

In MainPage.xaml I have the procedure `RootFrame_Navigating`:

```
public static void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("/MainPage.xaml") != true)
        return;
    // Change the current navigation
    e.Cancel = true;
    App.RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
    {
        string confronto = (string)MainPage.Impostazioni.appSettings["lingua"];
        if ((confronto == "italiano") || (confronto == "english"))
            App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?method=cancel%20navigation&time=", UriKind.Relative));
        else
            App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/StartMenu.xaml?method=cancel%20navigation&time=", UriKind.Relative));
    });
}
```

And this is how I save the language:

```
private void engLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Impostazioni.appSettings.Add("language", "english");
}

private void itaLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Impostazioni.appSettings.Add("language", "italiano");
}
```

The error is `KeyNotFoundException` because I'm using this variable before it's declared, I suppose ... How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method ([`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc614991%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)) for just this purpose.

```
If (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("language"))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in App.xaml create  setting liks and just keep it blank.

```
Impostazioni.ApplicationSettings.Add("language","");
```

after this u will be able to use this code of yours

```
private void engLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Impostazioni.appSettings.Add("language", "english");
    }
```

hopefully it ll work.

Comment: Yes, but in this way, everytime I open the application, the setting will be initialized to blank, so it won't be able to set the correct language... :\

Comment: If i am not wrong these app settings remains until to remove them(just like isolated storage) or only after you uninstall the app. if they do not then try using IsolatedStorege.ApplicationSettings

Comment: I get this error:
Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve Phone's Language? So that I choose the language by the phone language... thanks :)

Comment: You can use system.Globalization library  [link](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/06/retreive-the-country-name-in-windows-phone-7/)